# Use ls command and sort files and directories by type

Tags: sorting, types, ls

I looked at the [documentation](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ls1.html) of `ls` command, but I haven't found any `[option]` that does it.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Maybe this answer from [SuperUsers](http://superuser.com/questions/19781/make-ls-sort-by-file-type-then-name) will help you

Comment: How do you define "type"? Do you want to look at extensions or do you want to do what `file(1)` does?

Comment: Type = file extensions.

Comment: Manfre Radlwimmer, the second answer of your link was useful: 

$ ls --group-directories-first
(man ls is your friend!)